# Do Messianic Jews adhere to the Talmud?

Tags: judaism, messianic-judaism

Messianic Jews are Jews that believe Jesus is their Messiah. Do they in general consider the Talmud to be authoritative and something they must adhere to?

Answer (score 1):

There is no agreement on this within the movement:

- some believe that adherence to the Oral Law, as encompassed by the Talmud, is against Messianic beliefs
- some deny the authority of the Pharisees, believing that they were superseded, and their teachings contradicted, by Messianism
- some call rabbinic commentaries such as the Mishnah and the Talmud "dangerous and state that followers of rabbinic and halakhic explanations and commentaries are not believers in Jesus as the Messiah
- some are selective in their applications of Talmudic law
- some exercise serious observance of Jewish halakha

Comment: Do you have a few references to examples?

Comment: 1) Burgess, Stanley M., ed. (2006). Encyclopedia of Pentecostal and Charismatic Christianity. Routledge. ISBN 978-0-415-96966-6. 2) [Messiancis and the Talmud](https://messianicapologetics.net/messianics-and-the-talmud/) 3)[Introduction to Messianic Judaism](https://books.google.be/books?id=3jf-epevPJ4C&pg=PT110#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you could edit those into the answer please.